# How to find where a jack stereo cable is interrupted

Tags: cables, stereo

I have a jack stereo cable like the one in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fw6nd1WObhA).
It stopped working correctly (only one side of the audio could be heard), and when I unscrewed the male and female plugs, both looked a bit iffy.
So, to attempt a cleaner repair, I cut off both ends, stripped the cable as shown, and tested the connectivity using the 'Ohm' setting of a tester.
And discovered that the white conductor is interrupted... the other two are fine.

**Q: is there any way to find *where* along the cable the interruption is (it's about 2 m long), obviously without cutting it at intervals and retesting each time?**

Comment: when you know where it is, what then?

Comment: I have attempted such repairs and the copper is usually insanely thin. You can make electrical connection again, but unless you cut the cable short and terminate with a new jack, your better option is to buy a new cable set with molded jack.

Comment: @danmcb : I cut it there and use the longer piece to reattach the plugs. So I don't have to buy a new cable. 2 m is more than I need, although I was hoping to be left with 1.5 m at least.

Comment: @winny : indeed, very thin, but as long as they work it's fine by me... it's hard to find this cable where I live, I would have to order it online and then the delivery is more expensive than the thing itself.

Comment: Have you verified that the problem is the cable and not the things the cable is plugged into?

Comment: @ScottSeidman : yes.

Comment: bend the cable every which way you can think of, while measuring continuity ... DMM beeper is useful for this

Comment: if you are using it for line level signals, screened cable is usually unnecessary. I've made such cables from 3 lengths of 7/0.2 twisted together, many times and never had problems. The advantage is that 7/0.2 is pretty robust and very easy to solder.

Comment: @jsotola : sorry, I don't get what you mean. Do you mean that by bending the cable the connection may be re-established?

Comment: yes ... that's how you may be able to locate the break

Comment: Unless it's a permanent break that does not get fixed by bending the cable. I still wonder how it got damaged, it is old but it really looks fine from outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your meter can measure capacitance, measure capacitance of the broken conductor to the good conductors at both ends, the distance from each end to the break will be approximately proportional to the capacitance.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately no, it cannot measure capacitance :/
I think I'll just have to buy a new cable, or just try cutting off 10 cm at a time on either end until it is connected again. Of course if the interruption is in the middle, yeah... :D
Strange though, the cable does not look damaged or bent anywhere...

Comment: usually they break near the ends,  pull on the broken conductor at each end it might be loose. if that fails, cut 5cm off each end if that does not work cut it in half, worst case you're left with a 95cm cable.

Comment: Thank you again, very pragmatic and useful advice!

Answer (score 1):

I think the capacimeter is the best answer. However, if you end up choosing to cut the cable at intervals, you can do it dichotomously to spare some cuts (it means, first cut it in half, check which half is faulty, then cut the wrong half in half, check which of the new two halves is faulty, etc.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I understand this answer :) and it's quite good advice in fact, because OK, I must accept to lose upfront half of the cable, but then I avoid cutting off pieces on a side that may be good.